# iOS app is frozen for 10 seconds on launch on line "setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack"

Tags: ios, ios5

First of all I have no idea what causes the issue and I can reproduce it only after device hardware restart. The app is fine after that.

- I use MagicalRecords lib.
- "[MagicalRecordHelpers
  setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack]" is called inside "application:
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:".
- After a few inner method calls and
  it's freezes for 10–15 seconds.

This is a log from Console where you can see call's details and timings. I just noticed that it's frozen by some strange (for me) low level calls.

```
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: start
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: DATA > migration
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: --- MR_coordinatorWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: --- MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: --- MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x3ed04728) Creating MOContext  *** On Main Thread ***
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x3ed04728) Creating context in Context Private Queue Mode
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: --- MR_setDefaultContext
Apr 11 17:39:21 unknown librariand[132] <Notice>: changing log level to 5
Apr 11 17:39:22 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.ubd) Exited with code: 10
Apr 11 17:39:22 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.ubd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
> 
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown librariand[132] <Error>: client process 130 does not have a valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown librariand[132] <Error>: error in handle_container_path_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/9/The client process does not have a valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown librariand[132] <Error>: client process 130 does not have a valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown librariand[132] <Error>: error in handle_container_path_request: LibrarianErrorDomain/9/The client process does not have a valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlement
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: --- setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed END
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: DATA > prefilling
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: UI
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown librariand[132] <Warning>: items added, refreshing item updates for file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/
Apr 11 17:39:33 unknown MY_APP[130] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: end
```

I don't really know if users face this problem. But if the do it may probably crash on start for many of them.

I know the problem is difficult to analyze, but if you have at least any related thought or just an idea, please share. Also please ask for any details.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code instead of the NSLogs. Specifically the `setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack` function.

Comment: I add similar logs but im using NSManagedDocument, Did you ever found what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like iCloud is trying to initialize there. I've heard this has been a problem, however, Apple suggests calling the URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: on NSFileManager. This is what's going on under the covers in that method, but it seems that method is also choking at some point...not sure what to do other than in the **NSManagedObjectContext** category method **MR_observeiCloudChangesInCoordinator**, comment out the lines that call **isICloudEnabled**...that is most likely your solution for now :(